# Bluetooth repeater/bridge

Tags: pi-3, networking, wireless, bluetooth

I was wondering if somebody already tried to create some sort of Bluetooth repeater or bridge? I know they are not the same, but both systems should work for my needs.

In detail, I am trying to create a bridge like this:

```
|Device_A|
    |
    | Bluetooth link
    |
 |RPI_A|
    I
    I WiFi/ Ethernet link
    I
 |RPI_B|
    |
    | Bluetooth link
    |
|Device_B|
```

Here, `RPI_A` and `RPI_B` could be combined to `RPI_C` to form a repeater instead of a bridge.

However, I could not find any solutions. To my knowledge, there are - if any - only expensive bridges/repeaters. So I thought I could either use the internal Bluetooth chip on the Raspberry Pi 3 or buy some cheap Bluetooth dongles and build a bridge.

Does anybody have helpful hints on how to tackle this problem or has done this before? My guess is that I can not simply get the input of one Bluetooth dongle and transmit it to another Raspberry.

Comment: This is a cool idea. What's the application, in more detail? What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: @user2497 I am researching whether it is possible to bypass Googles SmartLock mechanism or not. My hypothesis is that it can not prevent such relay attacks from happening. There are other methods such as Windows' dynamic lock or Apple's auto unlock where I suspect a similar outcome. All these systems sense if a specific Bluetooth device is in range of, e.g., your notebook and automatically log into/out of your user account.

Comment: here are some useful tools: https://github.com/DigitalSecurity/btlejuice, you could maybe adapt the python/node bindings to your needs. I guess you're looking for something like "GATT>IP"

Comment: @Gotschi perfect! This looks very promising, I will look into it and keep you guys updated. Cheers

Comment: @NilsQ. Please do.

Comment: @user2497, another use case would be to leave a phone in a room in a big multi-story house and have smartwatches/headphones still connected to the phone via bluetooth while roaming around the house outisde of standard 10m bluetooth range.

Comment: @IvanFrolov Yes, but OP wanted to do something that seems non-trivial, at least with standard firmware.